# Deleting rows from database while keeping id continuity

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle

I have a table with 10 rows with ids 1-10. I want to delete row 5 and 8 and I want to IDs to be updated so that they are 1-8 and not 1-4, 6-7 and 9-10. I don't want to run a massive amount of update statements or do it by hand. Also I need solutions that work for both SQLServer and Oracle databases. I think something like a procedure could do that but I have no idea how to create one or how to go about it.

Comment: Unless you have a *really*, *really* good reason, you should not care what the specific value is of an automatically generated id.  Holes are not a problem for the database.

Comment: Why the requirement to keep id continuity?

Comment: For OCD reasons. Also the IDs are not auto-generated it is a hand-made non editable table that contains static business-logic data.

Comment: And does the id column have foreign keys from other tables referencing it? Because if so, "OCD reasons" aren't - IMHO - a valid reason for making this update.

Comment: "OCD reasons" are a terrible reason to do any kind of work, unless you're paying your own salary.

Comment: @ Boneist No as I said it is a static business-logic data table.

@ JeffreyKemp Well if one is trying to be a perfectionist, I believe presentation is also important. Not leaving gaps in the table's data is like removing garbage code and comments (in my opinion).

Comment: To me, a "static business-logic data table" means that you're going to be referencing the heck out of that table all over the place - ie. foreign keys from other tables back to this static data table. Otherwise, why have it? However, it sounds like this isn't the case in your situation - to which I would respond: why worry about the "prettiness" of your id column's data when your database design looks to be ... not the best. Of course, this is pure speculation on my part, based on what you've said.

Comment: @Boneist Well all of this data could have been statically typed in our code indeed but we put it in a database for scalability. The code that uses these entries is made in such a way that it can understand new entries without having to update its core. If the business logic were to be expanded, now we only have to add a new database entry whereas without this table we would have to change our core code to support it.

Comment: Ah, ok, so it's a code config table. I would still question the need to update the ids though; seems like unnecessary work. In fact, if the ids are entirely random, why are they there at all? Get rid of them, and voila, no issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should include what you have tried, anyways you can run this query until no more updates happen (if you don't care about performance, better order by id and use the row number as the other answers do):

```
UPDATE myTable t SET id = id - 1 WHERE id <> 1 AND
   NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM myTable s WHERE s.id = t.id - 1)
```

Comment: This doesn't work; it leaves you with ids 1-5, 7-8 and 10, which is not what the OP wanted.

Comment: @Boneist not really "repeat until nore updates happen", to see how that is done in PL/SQL requires max 30s search time, so I didn't show it. Also I know it's not good, that's why I upvoted the other answers, but it is still a solution.

Comment: Ah, I missed that step. But the OP didn't want to have to run multiple update statements, so...

Comment: @Boneist I was thinking about multiple in the sense of inert into... insert into ... insert into ... but that actually sounds pretty stupid, still because he even mentions doing it manually, it might have been already an improvement for him.

Answer (score 3):

You really should not do that, as Gordon Linoff pointed out. If you still would do that, here is an `UPDATE`:

```
update t_table t set id = (
    select newid from (
        select id, row_number() over (order by id) newid from t_table
    ) x
    where x.id = t.id
)
```

The syntax should probably work in both Oracle and MSSQL (only tested in Oracle), as long as they permit to update a primary key at all.
Still, I would suggest against using this technique. If you want a consecutive integer column, use `row_number()` as it is used in the query above to generate one on the fly.

Comment: only issue there is that in Oracle, you can't update a column in the merge that's a part of the join condition, so your merge statement will result in 'ORA-38104: Columns referenced in the ON Clause cannot be updated: "T"."PRIMARY_KEY"'.

Comment: @Boneist Thanks for pointing that out. Changed it to an Update.

Answer (score 1):

In Oracle, it's easy - you'd just use the MERGE statement, along with the row_number() analytic function, like so:

```
drop table test1;

create table test1
as
select level id,
       level some_val
from   dual
connect by level <= 10;

delete from test1
where id in (5, 8);

merge into test1 tgt
using (select rowid row_id,
              id,
              row_number() over (order by id) rn
       from   test1) src
  on (tgt.rowid = src.row_id)
when matched then
update set tgt.id = src.rn;

commit;

select * from test1;

        ID   SOME_VAL
---------- ----------
         1          1
         2          2
         3          3
         4          4
         5          6
         6          7
         7          9
         8         10
```

ETA: I'd echo what the others have said regarding why you need to do this, however - especially if the id column is the primary key and there are foreign keys referencing it!